# Display a selected value in a dropdown using Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

Here is a snippet from my JSON

```
{
  "PreferredLanguage":"Italian",
  "PreferredLanguageDisplay":"Italiano",
   "Languages":[
     {"Selected":false,"Text":"English (UK)","Value":"0"}, 
     {"Selected":false,"Text":"English (US)","Value":"1"}, 
     {"Selected":true,"Text":"Italiano","Value":"2"}, 
     {"Selected":false,"Text":"Français","Value":"3"}
   ]
}
```

Now, I am binding a dropdown in Knockout to `Languages` thus:

```
<div class="item">
    <select data-bind="foreach: Languages(), value: PreferredLanguage">
        <option data-bind="text: Text"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

This all works but I am trying to do one more thing.  By default the first value in the `Languages` array selected but I want the option whose text matches `PreferredLanguageDisplay` to be selected.

I tried using the `if` binding butcouldn't get that to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: You should use the options binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the options binding as follow :

*View  :*

```
<select data-bind="options: Languages, value: PreferredLanguage, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue : 'Value'">
</select>
```

*View model :*

```
var vm = {

    "PreferredLanguage": ko.observable('2'), // Value of Italiano
    "PreferredLanguageDisplay": "Italiano",
        "Languages": [{
        "Text": "English (UK)",
            "Value": "0"
    }, {
        "Text": "English (US)",
            "Value": "1"
    }, {
        "Text": "Italiano",
            "Value": "2"
    }, {
        "Text": "Français",
            "Value": "3"
    }],

};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8aWEZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what @Anders suggested. Here is the actual doc:

- http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

Comment: This is for a multi-select list